# Values of dropdown lists are not passed back to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view model which consists of a patient object and Visits collection. The view model is populated with all the correct property values and the properties display correctly in the Edit view. I also verified the property values in the view model before the model was passed to the view in the Edit (GET) action of the controller.

The problem is, even if I change none of the properties while in the edit view, the properties  bound to dropdown lists (gender and condition) are not passed back to the Edit (POST) action of the controller. This results in an exception being thrown.

The properties have values but somewhere they are getting lost. How do I troubleshoot this?

ASP.NET MVC 4 RC

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    var patient = this.db.Patients.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    var visits = this.db.Visits.Where(v => v.PatientId == patient.Id && v.IsActive).OrderByDescending(v => v.VisitDate);

    PatientEditViewModel model = new PatientEditViewModel();
    model.Patient = patient;
    model.Visits = visits;

    if (patient == null)
    {
        return this.HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.GenderId = new SelectList(this.db.Genders, "Id", "Name", patient.GenderId);
    ViewBag.HandednessId = new SelectList(this.db.Handednesses, "Id", "Name", patient.HandednessId);

    return this.View(model);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PatientEditViewModel model)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<PatientEditViewModel, Patient>();

    var entity = Mapper.Map<PatientEditViewModel, Patient>(model);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        this.db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.db.SaveChanges();
    }

    this.ViewBag.GenderId = new SelectList(this.db.Genders, "Id", "Name", entity.GenderId);
    this.ViewBag.HandednessId = new SelectList(this.db.Handednesses, "Id", "Name", entity.HandednessId);

    return this.View(model);
}
```

---

```
@model Web.Models.PatientEditViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "XXX";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Patient</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Patient.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Patient.GenderId, "Gender")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownFor("GenderId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Patient.GenderId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Patient.HandednessId, "Handedness")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownFor("HandednessId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Patient.HandednessId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Patient.Comments)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Patient.Comments)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Patient.Comments)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@Html.Partial("_CurrentAndPreviousVisits", Model.Visits)


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


}
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Show us the code for Get action, Post action and view

Comment: Question updated with code...

Comment: go through my samples   [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
  [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Is your view supposed to be DropDownListFor? I don't know what DropDownFor is, but it's not part of the default MVC helpers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `Html.DropDownFor` helper. Maybe you meant `Html.DropDownList` or `Html.DropDownListFor`. Personally I would recommend you the second and strongly typed version.

So in your `PatientEditViewModel` model you define the following properties:

```
public string GenderId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectList> Genders { get; set; }

public string HandednessId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectList> Handednesses { get; set; }
```

and then in your controller action you forget about `ViewBag` and properly populate your view model. So you replace the 2 lines of ViewBag with 2 lines of view model assignment:

```
model.Genders = new SelectList(this.db.Genders, "Id", "Name", patient.GenderId);
model.Handednesses = new SelectList(this.db.Handednesses, "Id", "Name", patient.HandednessId);
```

and in your view you use the strongly typed versions of the helpers:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GenderId, Model.Genders)
```

and:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HandednessId, Model.Handednesses)
```

Now inside your POST action you will get the 2 selected values inside the `GenderId` and `HandednessId` properties of your view model. Obviously in your POST action if you want to redisplay the same view you remove the 2 lines of ViewCrap (pardon I meant ViewBag) with the 2 lines of view model property assignment.